# Why is $\Bbb Z_3$ cyclic?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I want to prove that $\Bbb Z_3$, defined as the only group of order $3$, is cyclic.

The identity element $e$ needs to be there, so $\Bbb Z_3=\{a,b,e\}$. Now, $ab$ can't be nor $a$ or $b$, otherwise one of them would be $e$, so $ab=e \implies b=a^{-1}$. Now, the next step would be proving that $a^2=a^{-1}$, but why is that necessary? Couldn't the multiplication table be like this? $$ab=ba=e, \quad a^2=a, \quad ({a^{-1}})^2=a^{-1}$$

Comment: If $a^2 = a$ then it isn't cyclic.  Anyway $a^2 =a$ is not possible and you must prove that $a^2 = a^{-1} = b$.

Comment: if $a^2 = a$ then $a = e$, surely? As per your argument for $ab$.

Comment: To be cyclic you must prove the elements are precisely $e,a,a^2$.  Nothing more, nothing less. You have prove the elements are $e,a,a^{-1}$.  You are not done.  You must prove $a^2 = a^{-1}$.  (and as a side note, no, $a^2 = a$ is not an option.  But you must prove it is not an option.)

Comment: Every group of prime order is cyclic and unique up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $a^2 = a$  we can multiply both sides with $a^{-1}$ and thus obtaining $a=e$. This is a contradiction(since $a$ and $e$ are two different elements), so you cannot have the multiplication table stated.

Answer (score 2):

By *Lagrange's theorem*, the order of $a$ is divisor of $3$. So either it is $1$, which means $a=e$, which is excluded, or it is $3$, i.e. $a^3=e$, which is equivalent to $a^2=a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$a^2$ could be $1$ or $a$ or $b$.

- In the first case $ab\ne aa=1$ and $ab\ne a1=a$ and $ab\ne 1b=b$.
- In the second $a=a1\ne aa=a$

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking why we must prove it?  Or why it must be true.

Why we must prove it:  We need to prove any 3 element group is cyclic.  that means there is an element $a \ne e$ and the three elements are precisely $e,a$ and $a^2$.

So if you have that the elements are $e,a, a^{-1}$ you haven't proven that yet.  You have to prove the third element is $a^2$.  It's not enough to prove it is $a^{-1}$.

that's why you have to prove it.

Why must it be true:  Well, .... that's what you have to prove, isn't it?

You ask if $a^2 = a$ isn't possible.  $a^2 = \color{red}a\color{blue}a \ne \color{red}a$ for the *exact*  same reason $\color{red}a\color{blue}b \ne \color{red}a$.

.... which come to think of it you didn't give a good reason.

$e$ is the identity element but there is nothing in the definition of a group that says that $e$ is the *only* identity, nor does it mean if $ab = b$ that $a=e$.  Maybe there are two elements $e$ and $a$ where $ab=b$ and $eb=b$

But note that  if $ab = a$ then $a^{-1}ab= a^{-1}a$.  But $a^{-1}ab = eb =b$ and $a^{-1}a = e$ so that can only happen if $b=e$.

Likewise if $a^2 = a$ then $a^{-1}a^2 = a^{-1}a$.  But $a^{-1}a^2 = a^{-1}aa =ea =a$ and $a^{-1}a = e$ so $a^2 = a\implies a = e$.  (That's true for *all* groups).

Comment: Wait, isn't the identity element unique? I mean, if there is another element $x$ for which $gx=g \forall g$, doesn't this imply that $x=e$?

Comment: it's easy to prove.  But it must *be* proven.  " I mean, if there is another element x for which gx=g∀g, doesn't this imply that x=e?"  First of all, we aren't talking about $gx= g$ for *all* $g$, we are just talking about $gx = g$ for *ONE* $g$.  ANd second ***WHY*** does it imply that.  That assumption *must* be proven.